# Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]'

Tags: swift

I am getting the error message in my if statement

```
if (SelectedJobFunctions.contains(JobFunctions[indexPath.row])){
            cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        }
        else {
            cell.accessoryType = .None
        }
```

This is the array

```
var JobFunctions = ["Cleaning","Admin","Slacking","Business"]
var SelectedJobFunctions = []
```

Im trying to see if the user has selected a function and if it has been selected with will be in the `SelectedJobFunctions` array, it would add a checkmark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifing the type of array in the SelectedJobFunctions, like this

```
   var JobFunctions = ["Cleaning","Admin","Slacking","Business"]
   var SelectedJobFunctions:[String] = []
   if (SelectedJobFunctions.contains(JobFunctions[indexPath.row])){
               cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
   }
   else {
              cell.accessoryType = .None
   }
```